# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple even when indices appears to be an integer

Tags: python, list, datetime, time

I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Even though, as far as my limited understanding goes, the list index is an integer.

This code:

```py
date_time_list = [(1, 1902), (1, 704), (2, 2106), (2, 303), (3, 1706),(3, 415), (4, 2356), (4, 234)]

for i in date_time_list:
    date_time_obj.append(datetime.datetime(2019, date_time_list[i][0], 10, 20))
```

Gives me the above TypeError.

Though when I do:

```
In: type(date_time_list[0][0])
Out: int
```

What is going on here?

Comment: `i` here is a tuple like `type(data_time_list[0])`

Comment: what you meant is probably `for i in range(len(date_time_list))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo he could also do it this way, he'd just use `i` to represent each element in the `date_time_list`. See my answer

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Sure thing! your answer is great. I upvote it :) just saying according to the OP's line of thought (according to the code) probably this is what he meant to do... surely I would do it like in your answer

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a tuple, not an `int`, which is where your error is coming from.

You probably want:

```
for i in date_time_list:
    date_time_obj.append(datetime.datetime(2019, i[0], 10, 20))
```

instead.